# How can I view the responses to the questions that I have flagged?

Tags: support

On Stack Overflow, is there any way for users to view the actions that have been taken for the questions that they have flagged? I recently tried to move one of my own questions for stackoverflow to https://unix.stackexchange.com/, but I still don't know whether my request was accepted or declined, or whether a response is still pending or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click your username. In your profile information is a category called `helpful flags`, whose number is a hyperlink. This takes you to a page wherein you can see whether or not your flags were deemed helpful. As you would expect, each question is a link to the flagged post.

Note that, even if your flags were deemed helpful, that does not necessarily mean action was taken. This is because a certain number of flags are required for action. A flag can be helpful, even if not enough flags are present to take action.

On the right hand side, however, you can see how many of your flags are pending review.

Comment: Is there any way to see whether an action was taken for each flag? I actually saw a list like this once (with a list of responses from moderators), but now I can't remember where I saw it.

Comment: I'm not sure a user has access to action taken. Generally, by following the link, you can tell.